# when and how can I write a thank you letter for my professor?

Tags: professorship, email, coursework, course-evaluation

I took a course with my supervisor this semester. the class is finished. 
I really enjoyed every moment in class. I could ask all of my questions very easily and he always was available to answer them. it was an interactive class.
The final exam is not taken yet.
I wanted to write a thank you letter to my professor and thanking him for the course.
I was wondering if you could tell me when is the appropriate time to send him an email. and what should I say to him in my email?

Comment: You need to re-read the answers and especially some of the comments made to the question you asked here : https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/112294/72855

Comment: It seems a bit odd to email your personal advisor, whom you presumably see at least four days a week ... why not just say so in person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with [OBu's answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/115793/9553) (and gave it +1) that what you've written is perfect, exactly the kind of note any instructor would love to receive from a student.  But hold off until you have your final grade.  You'll make his day.  If you'd really like to hit a home run with your instructor, consider also posting it to [RateMyProfessors.com](https://www.ratemyprofessors.com).

Comment: Since I started my MSc degree, I have actually started writing thank you letters to every lecturer that taught me a course, directly after receiving the grade. It didn't matter if I was very involved in the course or not, and it didn't matter if I got the grade I wanted or not. Just a simple "thank you" letter, of course if I am more involved, the letter would hit better, but I think it is always important to appreciate the effort lecturers make in teaching their courses. (I actually missed a letter to one of my professors, and till this day I regret not writing to him, because he deserved it)

Answer (score 2):

The text you are writing here is perfect! It is personal, highlights the relevant aspects, and it is not overly enthusiastic.

I personally would send it after the exam was taken and graded.

Comment: what do you mean by "overly enthusiastic."? can you explain more pls.

Comment: sometimes students think, that they should include superlative after superlative in such a letter - which leads to the assumption, that this is not a honest opinion.

Comment: Yes, that kinda writing is not good. how is mine? should I add anything? @OBu

Comment: Maybe you can add some details about your personal highlights or which classes were best. If you have something which could be improved, you can add this, too. Don't make the overall e-mail too long, though.

Comment: I just took one class with him. you mean telling about other classes with other profs which were good?

Comment: sorry, I ment which specific lessons / sub-topics...

Answer (score 1):

The timing depends on the relationship you already have. In most cases it would be best to wait until after the course is completed and graded. You don't want to be perceived incorrectly as trying to influence the grades. But if the relationship is longstanding, then the timing matters less. I've had professors that I could thank at any time without misunderstanding, and others, somewhat more formal, for whom it would be better to wait.

But writing is a good thing to do. So is coming back to the university ten years later and thanking some of your professors who especially helped you and bring them up to date on your professional progress.